# Firebird Trigger Deadlock

Tags: sql, triggers, firebird, database-deadlocks

I've very little experience with databases and have run in to a problem with a trigger causing a deadlock in a firebird 2.5 database.

There is two tables in the database . When  items are added or removed from the ITEMS table a Trigger updates STATS.ITEMCOUNT & STATS.SIZE. There are 4 triggers in total 2 Incrementing & and two decrementing.

The stats table has a single row and is used to track what in the database.    Am I doing this the wrong way?  And If not is there a work round.

A deadlock occurs within the first few minutes of starting the application.

UPDATE1:  Posted all triggers.

UPDATE2: Posted ExecuteNonQuery Method

UPDATE3: Deadlocks still occur even when using the view method kindly suggested by **pilcrow**. In fact I even tried using a stored procedure which deadlocked again. Wrapping the select statement in a transaction also failed because the Firebird Ado provider does not support parallel transactions.

```
public void ExecuteNonQuery(string NonQuery)
        {
            try
            {
                FbCommand FBC = new FbCommand(NonQuery, DBConnection);
                FBC.ExecuteNonQuery();
                FBC.Dispose();
            }
            catch (FbException e)
            {
                Log.FatalException("Database NonQuery Error", e);
            }

        }

        }
```

Database

```
** Tables **

CREATE TABLE ITEMS (
    ID              ID NOT NULL /* ID = VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL */,
    EXPIRYTIME      EXPIRYTIME NOT NULL /* EXPIRYTIME = BIGINT NOT NULL */,
    ITEMSIZE        ITEMSIZE /* ITEMSIZE = BIGINT NOT NULL */,
    ACCESSCOUNT     ACCESSCOUNT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL /* ACCESSCOUNT = INTEGER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL */,
    LASTACCESSTIME  LASTACCESSTIME /* LASTACCESSTIME = TIMESTAMP NOT NULL */
);


CREATE TABLE STATS (
    INSTANCE            SMALLINT,
    SIZE                BIGINT DEFAULT 0,
    ITEMCOUNT  BIGINT DEFAULT 0,
    HITS       BIGINT DEFAULT 0,
    MISSES     BIGINT DEFAULT 0
);
```

** Triggers **

```
   /* Trigger: TRG_INCREMENT_ITEMCOUNT_STATS */
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TRG_INCREMENT_ITEMCOUNT_STATS FOR ITEMS
ACTIVE AFTER INSERT POSITION 1
AS
begin
 UPDATE STATS SET ITEMCOUNT = ITEMCOUNT + 1 WHERE INSTANCE = '0';
end

/* Trigger: TRG_DECREMENT_ITEMCOUNT_STATS */
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TRG_DECREMENT_ITEMCOUNT_STATS FOR ITEMS
ACTIVE AFTER DELETE POSITION 2
AS
begin
UPDATE STATS SET ITEMCOUNT = ITEMCOUNT - 1 WHERE INSTANCE = '0';
end

/* Trigger: TRG_INCREMENT_HITS_STATS */
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TRG_INCREMENT_HITS_STATS FOR ITEMS
ACTIVE AFTER UPDATE POSITION 3
AS
begin
UPDATE STATS SET HITS = HITS + 1 WHERE INSTANCE = '0';
end

/* Trigger: TRG_INCREMENT_SIZE_STATS */
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TRG_INCREMENT_SIZE_STATS FOR ITEMS
ACTIVE AFTER INSERT POSITION 4
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE STATS SET SIZE = SIZE + NEW.ITEMSIZE WHERE INSTANCE = 0;
END

/* Trigger: TRG_DECREMENT_CACHESIZE_STATS */
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TRG_DECREMENT_CACHESIZE_STATS FOR ITEMS
ACTIVE AFTER DELETE POSITION 5
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE STATS SET SIZE = SIZE - OLD.ITEMSIZE WHERE INSTANCE = 0;
END
```

Comment: Guess deadlock occurs only when multiple users work simultaneously with database?

Comment: Its an embedded database wit no outside users. The code that reads & writes to the database is just a standard class although many hundreds of items are being added and removed at the same time. The deadlock problem only occurs with the triggers..

Comment: What "at the same time" means? Is application multithreaded?

Comment: One class adds item to the database. Another class on its own thread removes items if they are expired.  The triggers fire when items are added and removed.  If the triggers are disabled deadlock never occurs.

Comment: Every class instance has its own transaction?

Comment: Not explicitly.  I believe FB Ado provider does the transaction internally.  Just posted the code that talks to the database.  All Non Queries pass thru this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using

```
.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted;
```

in the connection string.

Comment: Im not sure about that as ".IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Snapshot" worked as well.

Comment: The Transaction configuration for Snapshot is not the same as for ReadCommitted, so that could account for the difference. Could you create a simple project which clearly reproduces this problem and add it to a new ticket on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org ?

Answer (score 1):

Deadlock occurs because two threads attempt to update the same row simultaneously. Simpliest solution in this case would be to use single transaction and critical section to prevent simultaneous updates. It would require literally a couple of lines of code.

Other way would require redesign of a table with total information.

Comment: Just to clarify the only thing that updates the STATS table are the database triggers. My code currently does not access the stats table at all. When these trigger are disabled the deadlock NEVER occurs.  The Fbexception message always references one of the triggers on deadlock.  I cannot think of anything I could do or not do in code to prevent this from happening.

Comment: It does not matter whether updates to stat table are made indirectly or from triggers. Deadlock will occur in any case when the same row is being updated simultaneously from two or more separate transactions.

Comment: Just updated the post to show all triggers. In that case should I be doing this a different way? I thought the triggers would handle concurrency internally.

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> *... is there a work round.*

There is at least one other approach.  Instead of using triggers to precompute aggregated counts and sizes, could you simply compute them on demand in a VIEW like so:

```
CREATE VIEW stats (instance, size, itemcount, hits, misses) AS
   SELECT CAST(0 AS SMALLINT),
          CAST(COALESCE(SUM(items.itemsize), 0) AS BIGINT),
          CAST(COUNT('x') AS BIGINT),
          CAST(COALESCE(SUM(items.accesscount), 0) AS BIGINT), -- just guessing here
          0                                                    -- but see below
     FROM items;
```

(Note:  I'm guessing that your HITS are the sum of ITEMS.ACCESSCOUNT, as the UPDATE trigger and column names suggest.  You don't tell us how you are recording MISSES now, but, if the application is directly incrementing STATS.MISSES at present, you could introduce a *new* table for that purpose, and then JOIN that table into the VIEW above.)

**You will still have to commit transactions appropriately, of course.**  The STATS view suggested above is only as accurate as completed, committed transactions it can see.

Comment: Your suggested workaround works. But takes serveral seconds to execute.  The DB currently has 250K records with 800K expected.  Am I working around a limation in firebird or databases in general?

Comment: @Canacourse - that sounds more like a tuning/indexes problem.  That volume of records should not be a problem for FB!

Comment: Disabled all triggers and using a cut down version of your suggested view as  a test. Basically the view just returns the sum of items.itemsize and is used as follows "SELECT * FROM STATS". But Deadlock problems again. I'd be Happy enough to just read committed transactions as you mentioned by does not seem to be happening. BTW items are being removed to/from the table in question constantly.   Do I need to do something with the transaction level on the select statement?  I wonder is this the same problem as mentioned here http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/deadlocked.html

Comment: Sorry your workaround is not working deadlock still happening so unmarking as answered.

Answer (score 0):

These problems are usually easier solved by using a record per change with a +1 or -1, and occassionaly (daily, weekly) processing the entire table to sum everything up and have only one record again. Next change will then again a +1 or -1 record and you query the sum total.

So you would have something like:

```
ITEM  COUNT
item1 10
item2 10
item1 1
item2 -1
item2 -1
item1 -1
```

and after the scheduled merge you get:

```
ITEM   COUNT
item1  10
item2  8
```

You can then add a view which simply sums the records per item.